# how do you connect to Oracle with sqlite3 in terminal?

Tags: oracle, sqlite

I would like to ru sqlite3 to connect to an Oracle db; but I can't find a tutorial that actually tell me the basics. I am using linux running sqlite3 via terminal

I assume that I need to connect to the db; I have a connection string to the db but I have no idea about how to tell sqlite3 to connect and open it.

Can anyone please point me to a solution? At themoment I use a program called squirrel sql, but I would like to use just the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that sqlite3 was also an interface able to open other db. I will use the correct version for Oracle db then. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 6):

You can't. Sqlite3 is

```
  sqlite3 - A command line interface for SQLite version 3
```

and Oracle is, well, Oracle with a similar - but different - tool named

```
 sqlplus
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm#BJECGGFH

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is a self contained SQL database engine, and what you are referring too is the command line version of that.

It,  unfortunately is not designed to work with anything else.

You will need to find something else to talk to Oracle.

Sorry.